# Java: Whitespace in HTML not recognized with Regex pattern

Tags: java, html, regex, parsing

Code:

```
static short state = 0;
static int td_number = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {

final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[\\s]*?\\d+\\.\\d+[\\s]*?");
final short TD_ENTRY = 0;
final short NO_ENTRY = 1;

HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback callback = new HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback() {
    public void handleText(char[] data, int pos) {
    switch (state) {
    case NO_ENTRY:
        break;
    case TD_ENTRY: {
        // We are in the right table column
        // Create string from char array
        String s = new String(data);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        boolean b = m.matches();
        // Check if data information has correct format (0.0)
        if (b) {

        }
    }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    state = NO_ENTRY;
    }

    public void handleStartTag(HTML.Tag tag, MutableAttributeSet set, int pos) {
    if (tag == HTML.Tag.TD) {
      //[...]
    }
    }
};

Reader reader = new StringReader(html);
try {
    new ParserDelegator().parse(reader, callback, false);
} catch (IOException e) {
}
}
```

I am trying to parse HTML with Regular Expressions.  The program reads the content of `td` tags within an html table. The content in the table cell should fit a special pattern defined in `Pattern p`.

The main problem is now that the regex pattern does not match for cell content like this " 0.1".
But if I define the `String s` manually with the value (" 0.1") in the code the pattern matches.

Furthermore if I copy the content of `char[] data` in debug mode and define `s` with this copied content the pattern does also not fit although it looks the same like the manually defined value from above.

Is it possible to find out which whitespace characters are really read?

It seems that the whitespace is not always a whitespace and therefore does not match with regex class [\s]. Is this possible?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for answers. It was really a whitespace character (\xA0) which was not recognized by \s regex class.

For all of you which downvote (really frustrating) my question simply missunderstood me. Maybe the problem was really the sentence "I want to parse HTML with regex" but in fact I simply have content from a HTML table cell with unknown whitespace characters ;-).

I think I had got the same problems with a library like jsoup.

Comment: This is your main problem: [Parsing Html The Cthulhu Way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html). Instead of RegEx, use a library like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)

Comment: You are breaking one of the 10 commandments of programming.  DO NOT use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Read this: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: @jlordo yes, but the trim() function does not remove the whitespaces for whatever reason.

Comment: "I am trying to parse HTML with Regular Expressions." Whenever you find yourself saying that, stop what you're doing and step away from the keyboard. Then, learn how to use an XML parser. Then--**only** then--should you continue.

Comment: HTML often contain non-breaking spaces (code-point 160) which are not matched by `\s` or by the definition of space used by `String.trim()`.  `\s` matches `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]` only and `trim` treats only code-points < 0x20 as space.

Comment: Thanks for downvoting my last 3 questions for whatever reason. It is really frustrating...thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java regexes, the non-breaking space character (NBSP, `U+00A0`) is traditionally not treated as whitespace for the purpose of matching `\s`.  If that's what's causing your problem, you just need to add it to your existing whitespace class:

```
"^[\\s\\xA0]*\\d+\\.\\d+[\\s\\xA0]*$"
```

There are other Unicode whitespace characters that aren't matched by `\s`, but none of them are anywhere as common as the NBSP.

Alternatively, if you're running Java 7+ you can specify [`UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` mode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) and go on using `\s`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet is too long, but as far as I understand you just need pattern to match something like `0.0`, `10.52` etc, i.e. floating point numbers? Use pattern `\\d+\\.\\d+`.

`\d+` means 1..n digits
`\.` means dot. A single dot `.` in regex means "any character"

Here is the usage example:

```
String str = "123.456";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.matches()) {
    // do something.
}
```

BTW, pay attention that `matches()` matches full line. If you want to match part of line use `find()` instead. I personally always use `find()` and use start and end line markers `^` and `$` into regex itself when needed.